# AES Encryption Java/plsql

Tags: java, encryption, plsql, aes

I need to implement the same encryption/decryption application on Java and plsql(DBMS_CRYPTO for Oracle 10g).

The both implementation are working fine but the pb here is that I am getting different output for the encryption of the same plain text. 
Below the both code used for the encryption/decryption process (Java and PLSQL).

I used the same encryption algorithm "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" for DBMS_CRYPTO and Java.The problem here is that I am getting different output for the encryption of the same plain text.

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class AESencrp {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";


    private static final byte[] keyValue = "MyEncryptionKey1".getBytes();
    private static Key key;
    private static Cipher decryptor;
    private static Cipher encryptor;


    public static  void init() throws Exception 
    {

        key = generateKey();
        encryptor = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("12345678901234567890123456789012".toCharArray()));   
        decryptor=Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,iv);
        decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,iv);
    }




public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        byte[] encVal = encryptor.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

 public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {

        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = decryptor.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

 private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        if (key==null)
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
        return key;
}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        init();
        String password = "mypassword";
        String passwordEnc = AESencrp.encrypt(password);
        String passwordDec = AESencrp.decrypt(passwordEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    }
    }
```

- Java execution :

Plain Text : mypassword

Encrypted Text : +pvG30k4/KFkeim47tslFQ==

Decrypted Text : mypassword

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SYSADM.enc_dec
AS
     encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=DBMS_CRYPTO.AES_CBC_PKCS5; 
     encryption_key     RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('MyEncryptionKey1');


     FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC
     IS
        encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
     BEGIN
        encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
        (
           src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_plainText),
           typ => encryption_type,
           key => encryption_key,
           iv => hextoraw('12345678901234567890123456789012') 
        );
       RETURN encrypted_raw;
     END encrypt;
     FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
     IS
        decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
     BEGIN
        decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
        (
            src => p_encryptedText,
            typ => encryption_type,
            key => encryption_key,
            iv => hextoraw('12345678901234567890123456789012') 
        );
        RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (decrypted_raw));
     END decrypt;
END;
/
```

- PlSQL Execution:

select enc_dec.encrypt('mypassword') encrypted from dual;

FA9BC6DF4938FCA1647A29B8EEDB2515

select enc_dec.decrypt(enc_dec.encrypt('mypassword')) decrypted from dual;

mypassword

- Java -->+pvG30k4/KFkeim47tslFQ==
- PLSQL -->FA9BC6DF4938FCA1647A29B8EEDB2515

Can you please advise why we have this difference between the two encrypted output? there is a programming language dependency for the AES encrytion??

Answer (score 7):

The `+pvG30k4/KFkeim47tslFQ==` is in Base64 representation, while the
`FA9BC6DF4938FCA1647A29B8EEDB2515` is in HEX representation, but both strings represent the same value.

Decide on the single representation you will use and just convert one of the outputs to it.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested about the completed code for the PL/SQL based on Java code of first post.

**Encrpytion function:**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_ENCRYPT (p_plainText VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=DBMS_CRYPTO.AES_CBC_PKCS5; 
   encryption_key     RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('MyEncryptionKey1');
   encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
BEGIN
   encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
       (
           src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_plainText),
           typ => encryption_type,
           key => encryption_key,
           iv => hextoraw('12345678901234567890123456789012') 
       ); 
       RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (encrypted_raw));
END;
```

**Decryption function:**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_DECRYPT (p_input VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=DBMS_CRYPTO.AES_CBC_PKCS5; 
  encryption_key     RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('MyEncryptionKey1');
  decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
BEGIN
  decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
     (
         src => UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_input)),
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => encryption_key,
         iv => hextoraw('12345678901234567890123456789012') 
     );
     RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (decrypted_raw));
END;
```

**Validation:**

```sql
SELECT 'mypassword' INPUT, 
    F_ENCRYPT('mypassword') ENCRYPTED_RESULT,
    F_DECRYPT(F_ENCRYPT('mypassword')) DECRYPT_RESULT 
FROM DUAL;
```

**Validation Output:**

```
"INPUT"       "ENCRYPTED_RESULT"          "DECRYPT_RESULT"
"mypassword"  "+pvG30k4/KFkeim47tslFQ=="  "mypassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

Encrpytion / decryption using in oracle plsql

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY          "PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG" 
as
  FUNCTION decrypt_val( p_val IN RAW ) RETURN VARCHAR2  
  IS
    l_decrypted RAW(32);
    l_decrypted_string VARCHAR2(32);
    L_USER  varchar2(32);
    L_CHARACTER_SET varchar2(10);
    L_STRING varchar2(32);
    L_KEY raw(250);
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
        L_KEY := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW
                            ( data => '98345678901234567890123456789012',
                              DST_CHARSET => 'AL32UTF8' );
        L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                        + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC 
                                        + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

        l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt
                ( SRC => P_VAL,
                  TYP => L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                  key => L_KEY );

        l_decrypted_string := utl_i18n.raw_to_char
                    ( data => l_decrypted ,
                      src_charset => 'AL32UTF8' );
        RETURN l_decrypted_string;

  end DECRYPT_VAL;

  FUNCTION encrypt_val( p_val IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  is
    L_VAL RAW(32);
    L_ENCRYPTED raw(32);
    L_CHARACTER_SET varchar2(10);
    L_STRING varchar2(32);
    L_KEY RAW(250);
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
  begin


    L_KEY := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW
                        ( data => '98345678901234567890123456789012',
                          DST_CHARSET => 'AL32UTF8' );
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC 
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
    L_VAL := utl_i18n.string_to_raw
              ( data => p_val,
                dst_charset => 'AL32UTF8' );

    L_ENCRYPTED := dbms_crypto.encrypt
                   ( SRC => L_VAL,
                     TYP => L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                     key => L_KEY );


    return L_ENCRYPTED;
  EXCEPTION when OTHERS then
    RETURN SQLCODE||'-'||SQLERRM;
  end ENCRYPT_VAL;
end PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG;
```